# Awk - Append the output file and rename the input and output file

Tags: awk, append, match

I am looking to keep updating the File4 with the lines in file 3 starting with 99. I dont want awk to create a new File4 everytime.
Is there a way in awk to append the File4 all the time?

I am also looking to rename the file3 to file3.orig after the file is processed and file4 to file3.txt (the original name of the input file). So File4 would become File3 after processing and File3 would become File3.orig.

Any help is appreciated. 
Following is the script I am using.

**Script**

```
awk -F '\t', '/^99/' File3.txt > File4.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `>>` to append to an existing file:

```
#                      v-- here
awk '/^99/' File3.txt >> File4.txt
```

The file will be created if it doesn't exist, and appended to if it does. The file shuffle is best done afterwards:

```
mv File3.txt File3.orig
mv File4.txt File3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It resolved my issue. I have an issue though. If file4 is appended with the same set of data then it should be overwritten. Currently it is adding new lines instead of replacing. Is it possible through awk?

Comment: @HighTech we have no idea what you're talking about. Either you want to append to the file or overwrite the file. Saying "if I append it with the same data then it should be overwritten" doesn't parse. Ask a new question with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Will do :)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is appropriate for this task:

```
sed -i.orig -n '/^99/p' File3.txt
```